# Custom-made DAO: persist and record exists?

Tags: java, orm, dao

Just for the kick of it I'm writing some DAOs using plain JDBC.

At the moment I have an add method which saves entity data to a record. Now, I need to consider the case where a record already exists. I am guessing that in a ready-made ORM a persist method:

- Either checks if a record already exists. In this case, a SELECT on PK would be more efficient than a find ?
- Or an Exception is thrown when for example there's a conflicting primary key.
- Both ?

How is this usually done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical ORM like Hibernate, if you try to insert a transient entity that has the same identifier as a persistent entity, you will get a Constraint Violation exception.

I suggest you start a transaction, search/find an entity with the same identifier. If one exists, tell your application there is a problem, perhaps with a custom exception and rollback. If one doesn't exist, proceed by inserting the entity and commit the transaction.

This all depends on what constitutes an equal entity, ie. the PK, some unique field, etc. Usually, in an ORM, you'll be able to define a Generation Strategy for the entity identifier.